# Javascript DOM vs. XSLT Transformation performance-wise?

Tags: javascript, xslt, dom

I have a XML which works with an XSLT file that transforms the XML into a table on an HTML page.

I need to be able to update this table based on what the user selects from a drop down. Two options:

- send new parameters to XSLT processor, re-transform, clear old HTML content, places new HTML content; do this every time drop down changes value
- use javascript function to navigate HTML code directly and unhide/hide table data cells.

What would be better performance-wise?

EDIT: basically trying to apply filters

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. If one approach takes 1ms and the other takes 2ms, the difference is immaterial because no-one will notice. The right question is, if both approaches meet the performance requirement, which is better from the point of view of developer productivity, maintainability, etc?

Comment: Although I gave the answer below, I'm actually right with Michael Kay on this: that's the question you should be asking. I still think JavaScript would provide the most efficient solution, but I would be tempted to try out the XSLT solution just because it seems so neat (in the BrE sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option. There's a difference between modifying HTML and modifying *serialized DOM*. If you clear the DOM and give the browser a new HTML string to replace it with, it will have to serialize that HTML into DOM. If you use JavaScript to modify parts of the DOM, then not only will you skip that step, but you'll be taking advantage of optimisations in the rendering engine that restrict re-layouts to affected elements in the DOM, rather than the entire document.